# Backbone: $(e.currentTarget) returns undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

Another backbone question.
The view mentioned below renders fine.
However when clicking a link, the following line does not get executed:

```
console.log( $(e.currentTarget).data("id"));
```

But returns a message instead (so the event is triggered properly):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This is the view:

```
define([
    'jQuery', 
    'marionette', 
    'handlebars', 
    'text', 
    'text!templates/main_menu.html', 
], function ($, Marionette, Handlebars, Text, Main_menu_tpl) {
    'use strict';

    var Main_MenuView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        template: Handlebars.compile(Main_menu_tpl), 

        events: {
            'click .main_menu_item':'select_menu'
        },

        select_menu: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //Here is the problem 
            console.log( $(e.currentTarget).data("id"));
        },

        render: function () {
                    var wrapper  = {models: this.collection.toJSON()};
                    this.$el.html(this.template(wrapper));
                    return this;
        }
    });

    return Main_MenuView;
});
```

The template looks like this:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    {{#each models}}
        <li><a data-id="{{id}}" href="{{href}}" class='main_menu_item'">{{label}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you create a gist for this? I see that you're using a `Marionette.ItemView`, is there a reason why you're not using `Marionette.CollectionView` or `Marionette.CompositeView` to handle the collection?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni I created this gist with my source code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7527170. I'm not very experienced with this, so sorry if it doesn't follow certain conventions. For what concerns the Collection/CompositeView: I will look into this now, as I'm currently in a learning phase. I don't know if it will solve my problem with the click event though. Thanks

Comment: Oops I meant a jsfiddle, sorry about that. So we could see it in action, it's difficult just from the source code.

Comment: That may a bit hard. I run the application currently on localhost and cannot upload the files to an external server from here :-/ I manage my dependencies with requirejs, so I'm actually not too sure on how to do this with jsfiddle. Thanks anyhow. Btw, I checked out your remark, and a compositeview may be interesting for this functionality.

Comment: Yeah that would fit in your code ^^, I would suggest you to try and isolate the View with the bug, then repost with the fiddle, good luck with that.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Thanks again! I updated this post with the answer, using a compositeview instead of a regular itemview. I'm glad that I learned how to use this view today and immediately the difference collection <> compositeview. The problem was related to my dependency definition in requirejs for jquery.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I defined the jQuery dependency in main.js (using require.js) from a CDN as "jQuery" instead of "jquery".

However, due to some support of @AlbertoZaccagni, I used a `compositeview` for the first time to optimize my previous code.

The current code:

Create composite view to display based on collection

```
var main_menuView = new Main_menuCompositeView({collection: Header_menuCollection});
Zwoop.main_layout.headerRegion.show(main_menuView);
```

Creation of the itemview

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'marionette', 
    'handlebars', 
    'text', 
    'text!templates/main_menu_item_tpl.html', 
], function ($, Marionette, Handlebars, Text, Main_menu_item_tpl) {
    'use strict';

    var Main_Menu_ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "li",
        template: Handlebars.compile(Main_menu_item_tpl), 
        events: {
            'click .main_menu_item':'select_menu'
        },
        select_menu: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log( $(e.currentTarget).data("id"));
        }        
    });

    return Main_Menu_ItemView;
});
```

Creation of the compostie view:

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'marionette', 
    'handlebars', 
    'text', 
    'text!templates/main_menu_composite_tpl.html',     
    'views/main_menuItemView'
], function ($, Marionette, Handlebars, Text, Main_menu_composite_tpl, Main_menuItemView) {

    var Main_menuCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile(Main_menu_composite_tpl), 
        tagName: "ul",
        itemView: Main_menuItemView
    });

    return Main_menuCompositeView;
});
```